# Python: stop one incidence of recursive function and run another without resuming the first

Tags: python, function, tkinter, recursion, time

I am trying to make a game using a countdown timer for 60s.

My issue is that as the countdown timer is recursive, it keeps running until t == 0 when it runs the endgame() function.

if you pass the level, the initial countdown timer will still end after 60s which in turn will end the game. I need a way to run the next level without the initial countdown ending and ending the game.

I have tried using if True statements at the start of the function which only paused the loop until the next instance of the function started.

code:

```
from tkinter import *
import ctypes
from scrambld_back import *
from tkinter import font
import time
from nltk.corpus import words

user32 = ctypes.windll.user32
screensize = [user32.GetSystemMetrics(0), user32.GetSystemMetrics(1)]

root = Tk()
root.geometry(f'500x500+{screensize[1]-250}+100')
root.title('Scrambld')
root.configure(bg='white')

over = Tk()
over.geometry(f'500x500+{screensize[1]-250}+100')
root.title('Scrambld')
root.configure(bg='white')
over.iconify()

gamefont = font.Font(family='impact', size=30)
levelfont = font.Font(family='impact', size=20)

level = 0
Label(over, text='GAME OVER', font=gamefont)
Label(over, text=f'Level {level}', font=levelfont)

def endgame():
    over = Toplevel(root)
    over.geometry(f'500x500+{screensize[1]-250}+100')
    Label(over, text='GAME OVER', font=gamefont).place(x=250, y=215, anchor='center')
    Label(over, text=f'Level {level}', font=levelfont).place(x=250, y=285, anchor='center')

def play(level):
    t = 15
    gamewords = []
    for x in words.words():
        if len(x) == level+3:
            gamewords.append(x)
    word = gamewords[random.randint(0, len(gamewords))]
    gameplay = generate(list(word))
    Label(root, text=f'Level {level}', font=levelfont, bg='white').place(x=250, y=70, anchor='center')
    Label(root, text=gameplay, font=gamefont, bg='white', width=100).place(x=250, y=140, anchor='center')

    guess = Entry(root, font=levelfont, bg='white')
    guess.place(x=250, y=360, anchor='center')
    guess.bind('<Return>', lambda event, word=word: compare(event, word))

    def compare(event, word):
        if word.upper() == guess.get().upper():
            play(level+1)
        else:
            pass

    submit = Button(root, text='SUBMIT', font=levelfont, bg='white', width=21, command=lambda: compare(None, word))
    submit.place(x=250, y=420, anchor='center')

    timer = StringVar()
    Label(root, textvariable=timer, font=levelfont, bg='white', width=8).place(x=250, y=250, anchor='center')
    def countdown(t, lev):
        print(lev, level)
        print(t)
        t=int(t)-1
        if t < 10:
            t=f'0{t}'
        timer.set(f'00:{t}')
        root.update()
        if int(t) < 1 and lev == level:
            endgame()
        else:
            root.after(1000, lambda: countdown(t, lev))
        
    countdown(t, 1)

play(1)
```

Comment: This is not a good design.  You should not be creating new UI elements each time.  You need to set up the UI components ONCE, then when there is a correct guess you MODIFY the existing UI elements with the new information.  You then should have one single `countdown` function that stores its counter in a global, and the "reset_game" function should also reset the global countdown value.

Comment: FWIW,  you don't need `lambda` with `after` if you don't have named parameters. `root.after(1000, countdown, t, lev)` is how you can pass positional arguments using `after`.